# Setup incoming emails in WSS 3.0 and configure document library to receive emails

Tags: wss, sharepoint-2007

Does anyone have all the steps required to configure incoming email settings in MOSS 2007 including exchange and AD configuration changes? I would also like the steps to configure doc lib to receive emails

Thanks,
Milap

Answer (score 1):

There's a [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947%28office.12%29.aspx) that fully describes this.

Next time, you should post this question to [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/) for questions around server configuration and troubleshooting. You'll probably get better answers there :-)